# Private methods in PHP construct()

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Why can you only call private methods in a constructor?

I'm getting an error that "until the initialization of $this has completed, only private methods may be used".

Surprisingly there didn't seem to be any google results for the error message, or anything about doing `function __construct() { $this->publicMethod(); }` in the PHP docs.

Comment: Which php version is that?

Comment: +1 Arjan. Because this test works for me (http://pastebin.com/vN0MAHc9)

Comment: I'm able to call public methods from the constructor.

Comment: Are you pulling a fast one on us? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: I just tested this on a brand new server running PHP 5.3.10 and on codepad and didn't get that error: http://codepad.org/mxkP4NVk

Comment: Why don't you post your code so im would be obvious.

Comment: Just tried this under 5.5.3 and it worked just fine for me as well.

Comment: Works just fine: http://3v4l.org/5EQse Then again, you should not be doing any computation in constructors to begin with. It should contain only assignments.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it claim of error is unprovable.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must ... include valid code to reproduce it"